# Remove input R object in C++ function environment

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have an Rcpp function inside an R function. The R function produces some object (say a large list) and feeds it to the Rcpp function. Inside the Rcpp function, I process the R object, load the results to a number of C++ classes. Now the R object becomes useless. I want to wipe out the R object to make a memory-sufficient environment for the main algorithms.

The idea is:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void cppFun(List structuredData)
{
  // copy structuredData to C++ classes
  // Now I want structuredData gone to save memory
  // main algorithms ...
}

/***R
rFun(input)
{
  # R creates structuredData from input
  cppFun(structuredData)
}
*/
```

I tried calling R's "rm()" in C++ but it can only identify the object names in R's global environment. For example:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void cppFun()
{
  Language("rm", "globalDat").eval(); 
  Language("gc").eval();
}

/***R
globalDat = 1:10
ls() # shows "globalDat" is created.
cppFun() # shows "globalDat" is no longer in the environment.
ls()
*/
```

However, the following does not work:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void cppFun()
{
  Language("rm", "localDat").eval(); 
  Language("gc").eval();
}

/***R
rFun <- function (x)
{
  locDat = x
  ls() //  shows "x" and "locDat" are created
  cppFun()
  ls()
}

globalDat = 1:10
ls() # shows "globalDat" is created.
rFun(globalDat) # it will print "x","locDat" twice and a warning message: In rm("localDat") : object 'localDat' not found

locDat = globalDat
rFun(globalDat) # this will still remove "locDat" from the global environment.
*/
```

Am I on the right track to the goal? Is there any better way?

Thank you!

Thought of a hacky solution:

1. Write a shell class wrapping references to all the necessary C++ structured data classes.
2. In the R function, (i) process the input; (ii) feed the structured R data to the Rcpp function; (iii) in the Rcpp function, `new` a shell class object, load the structured R data; (iv) `memcpy` the shell class pointer to a `double` (8 bytes, if 32-bit system, use `int`); (v) return the `double`; (vi) return the `double` out of the R function. Now the structured R object dies while the `new`ed C++ shell object still lives. Call `gc()` for garbage collection.
3. Feed the `double` to the main C++/Rcpp function. `memcpy` this double to a shell class pointer. `delete` the shell class pointer before function returns.

Tests show the above works. Just found "external pointer" or `Rcpp::XPtr` designed for a similar purpose?

Answer (score 6):

Doing something along these lines would be known as an [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern), or highly counterproductive, in *Rcpp*. *Why* this is problematic is *Rcpp* performs a **shallow copy** when moving an *R* object to *C++*, which means the *R* object shares it's memory allocation with the instantiated *C++* object. If you were to *remove* the *R* object while a *C++* object references it, then you may run into trouble later in the process as a [segmentation fault (segfault)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) would likely occur.

Now, if you intend to do a **deep copy** from an *R* object into a *C++* structure, this wouldn't be quite as toxic. When doing deep copies, the data does *not* reference the original *R* object. However, this is *not* the default schema for *Rcpp*.

With this being said, I *strongly* discourage deleting objects mid-process. If you truly are memory strapped, try "chunking"/dividing the data more, perform operations with a database, buy additional RAM, or wait for [`ALTREP`](https://svn.r-project.org/R/branches/ALTREP/ALTREP.html).